Laravel-Backpack redirect to custom URL after create operation?
I have a situation like this, company->contact (one to many),
How can I redirect to contact/create with company id after the company created?
and where the save option configured, I am trying to remove 'Save and edit this item' option just from the Company create operation
array:2 [▼
  "active" => array:2 [▼
    "value" => "save_and_back"
    "label" => "Save and back"
  ]
  "options" => array:2 [▼
    "save_and_edit" => "Save and edit this item"
    "save_and_new" => "Save and new item"
  ]
] ```


Any idea how to customize form_save_buttons.blade.php just one controller, I am trying to remove save drop down from the Company How can I add 'CRUD::removeSaveAction('save_and_edit');' globally/config to affect all the controller

You can configure your save actions in your CrudController.
For example:
public function setupCreateOperation()
{
    CRUD::removeSaveAction('save_and_edit');
}

Have a look at: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-save-actions#default-save-actions
Cheers
